# How to show child QWidget titlebar when it's in parent QWidget layout?

Tags: qt, qwidget

I have parent widget and two child widgets in it (most likely I will put them in QSplitter). I want to display their names to clearly define where stuff is. Preferably in a frame at the top of the widget, like it's an embedded window.

How to do that in Qt?

Example of what I want to achieve: [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to achieve that:

- Use a `QMainWindow`.
- Set its central widget to a `QSplitter`.
- Add to `QMainWindow`s to the splitter.
- Add 2 `QToolBar`s to the sub main windows:

  - Top one for the title.
  - Bottom one as the actual tool bar.

**Example:**

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets>

int main(int argc,char*argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QMainWindow ww;

    ww.addToolBar("Main ToolBar");

    QSplitter *s = new QSplitter(Qt::Horizontal,&ww);
    ww.setCentralWidget(s);

    QMainWindow *left = new QMainWindow(&ww);
    QToolBar *t = new QToolBar("Left Toolbar");
    t->setMovable(false);
    t->addWidget(new QLabel("ChildWidget 1"));
    left->addToolBar(t);
    left->addToolBarBreak();
    left->addToolBar("Left tool bar");

    QMainWindow *right = new QMainWindow(&ww);
    QToolBar *t1 = new QToolBar("Right Toolbar");
    t1->setMovable(false);
    t1->addWidget(new QLabel("ChildWidget 2"));
    right->addToolBar(t1);
    right->addToolBarBreak();
    right->addToolBar("Right tool bar");

    s->addWidget(left);
    s->addWidget(right);

    ww.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

**Result:**

[image: 2 mainwindows in a mainwindow]